# start with prior reference on last select

Tags: plsql

I have a problem while inserting based on select query

I have a schema in the database with a parent-child relationship that looks like the following

```
A
 B
  C
   G
    L
F
 C
  G
   L
```

Notice how Element c is reused, because it´s aviable twice with different parent id, but element g is only aviable once, since the id of c is the same in both cases. The select prints everything as expected with the following query

```
select  id,
        parent_id,
        label
from    table
start   with parent_id is null
connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id   
order   siblings by sort
```

i am having around 2500 elements in this table, but in the end around 4000 are displayed because a few elemnts should be displayed multiple times at different places.

So, to identify both, the first and second g as unique elements, i have written the following insert statement

```
 insert into other_tale (id, parent_id, label)
 select create_id new_id, 
        prior ???,
        label,
 from   table
 start with parent_id is null
 connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id   
 order siblings by sort;
```

Here i am calling a procedure to generate a new id for each raw that has been found. Now i am stuck at the part where i do recieve the new id of the parent element. I know that i can refer to the prior parent_raw in the table beeing select, but am i able to somehow refer to the column new_id of the parent_element in the select?

Answer (score 0):

Create a package with 1 associative array `id_cache` and 2 functions: `f_clear_cache` and `f_generate_id`.

`f_clear_cache` deletes the cached ids - `id_cache.delete`.

`f_generate_id` takes *id* as argument and returns the *new_id*

1. check if the *new_id* was already generated - `id_cache.exists(id)`
2. if not, generate the *new_id* and cache it - `id_cache(id) := new_id`
3. return *new_id* - `return id_cache(id)`

finally use the function in your sql statement

```
insert into other_tale (id, parent_id, label)
select my_package.f_generate_id(id), 
       my_package.f_generate_id(parent_id),
       label
...
```

note: do not forget to call `f_clear_cache` when you want to generate new set of ids within the same session.